# Why linux provides so many apis to aquire time? Such as `gettimeofday`,`clock_gettime`,`time` etc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Why linux provides so many apis to aquire time? Such as `gettimeofday`,`clock_gettime`, `time`, etc?
Could anybody make it clear for me?

Comment: They return time in different ways.

Comment: @Barmar  Glad to see you again.Is there any difference as the aspect of the source of time?Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Read the documentation. `clock_gettime()` allows accessing multiple different clocks.

Comment: Questions about "why" an operating system or library does something in a particular way are generally not answerable here. We don't know what was in the mind of the designers, we can only speculate. Often it's just due to history. Unix has lots of mixtures because it combined different implementations like AT&T and BSD Unix.